# Debug.DrawLine: why does the line not disappear after duration?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Consider the following:

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 start = transform.position;
    Vector3 end = start + (gazeDistance * transform.forward);
    Debug.DrawLine(start, end, Color.green, 1f, false);
}
```

The line shows the player's current view direction (in the scene view) while the player is moving. 
I feel entitled by the code above to expect each line to disappear after `1f` second. But all the lines stay forever what leads to a `Color.green` mess. In other projects, however, this has been working correctly. 
 
Consequently I find myself in a rather distressed situation, from which I would like to escape with your help, esteemed reader. Feel thanked in advance!

Comment: Is your Time.timeScale set to 0 by chance?

Comment: Works for me. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Isn't Update called for every frame?

Comment: @Florianp.i. yes Update is called every frame, but the method parameter "1f" means that the line should disappear after 1 second.

Comment: Since there's no condition on drawing the line, and like @Florian p.i. said Update is called every frame, every frame is going to draw a new line.

Comment: Thank you @ErikOverflow, that was the problem

Comment: As an alternative to `Debug.DrawLine` you could / should use `Gizmos.DrawLine` in `OnDrawGizmos()`

Comment: What is the advantage of ```Gizmos.DrawLine```?

Comment: @BenjaminZach it is only for the Editor and not included in a build and thus saves resources on runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future users who run into this problem:

Debug.DrawLine's duration parameter *is affected* by Time.timeScale. If you set Time.timeScale to 0, lines with the duration greater than 0 will not disappear.